# How to read one column values from excel row by row and then write the result in another column in the same excel using Python?

Tags: python

How to read one column values from excel row by row, perform some operation on those indivisual value and then write the result in another column in the same excel using Python?

I could only find how to ready the entire excel / read the entire column using "pandas" :). I am new to python.

I tried using Pandas and it's too complex to even get a single value

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach, first read excel file.

```
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
    sheetname='Sheet1'
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheetname, header=0)
```

Then start gathering values of `column A`,

```
df['A']
```

Manipulating row

```
df['A'].loc[3]='33.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not much clear but as i think You want to get one by one value of rows of a column and apply some operation on it and then write it to another column in same excel file

[image]

here i am using the data set having 4 columns 4th column is empty.
now i will get the value of column 3 multiply it by 2 and will write it to column 4.

```
# import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# import excel file 
df = pd.read_excel('sales.xlsx')


for i in range(len(df)):
df.iloc[i,3]=df.iloc[i,2]*2 # getting value of each row of column 3 multiply it with 2 and store it on same row index in column 3 in datafram

df.to_csv('sales.xlsx') #now save the updated dataframe to same name of excel file
print(df) #enter code here
```

after running the above code the column 4 updated and the result is:
[image]